# How can I script vim to run perltidy on a buffer?

Tags: perl, vim

At my current job, we have coding-style standards that are different from the ones I normally follow. Fortunately, we have a canned RC file for `perltidy` that I can apply to reformat files before I submit them to our review process.

I have code for emacs that I use to run a command over a buffer and replace the buffer with the output, which I have adapted for this. But I sometimes alternate between emacs and vim, and would like to have the same capabilities there. I'm sure that this or something similar is simple and had been done and re-done many times over. But I've not had much luck finding any examples of vim-script that seem to do what I need. Which is, in essence, to be able to hit a key combo (like Ctrl-F6, what I use in emacs) and have the buffer be reformatted in-place by `perltidy`. While I'm a comfortable vim-user, I'm completely clueless at writing this sort of thing for vim.

Comment: Although it's not related to this question, Damian Conway has been showing all sorts of cool vim things in a series for developerWorks: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-vim-script-1/index.html

Answer (score 15):

After trying @hobbs answer I noticed that when filtering the entire buffer through `perltidy` the cursor returned to byte 1, and I had to make a mental note of the original line number so I could go back after `:Tidy` completed.

So building on @hobbs' and @Ignacio's answers, I added the following to my `.vimrc`:

```
"define :Tidy command to run perltidy on visual selection || entire buffer"
command -range=% -nargs=* Tidy <line1>,<line2>!perltidy

"run :Tidy on entire buffer and return cursor to (approximate) original position"
fun DoTidy()
    let l = line(".")
    let c = col(".")
    :Tidy
    call cursor(l, c)
endfun

"shortcut for normal mode to run on entire buffer then return to current line"
au Filetype perl nmap <F2> :call DoTidy()<CR>

"shortcut for visual mode to run on the current visual selection"
au Filetype perl vmap <F2> :Tidy<CR>
```

(closing `"` added to comments for SO syntax highlighting purposes (not required, but valid vim syntax))

`DoTidy()` will return the cursor to its original position plus or minus at most `X` bytes, where `X` is the number of bytes added/removed by `perltidy` relative to the original cursor position.  But this is fairly trivial as long as you keep things tidy :).

[Vim version: 7.2]

**EDIT:** Updated `DoTidy()` to incorporate @mikew's comment for readability and for compatibility with Vim 7.0

Comment: Thanks!  That cursor problem has been driving me crazy and I was too lazy to figure it out.  This is the best answer.

Comment: I don't know why the cursor saving code wasn't working for me. I replaced `let Pos = line2byte( line(".") )` with `let l= line(".")` and `let c = col(".")` then `call cursor(l,c)` and that works. Maybe vim is too old? using v7.0

Comment: @mikew I think your version makes more sense anyway :)

Comment: @hobbs I agree :) And since it's a compatibility issue I went ahead and updated the answer.

Comment: How to make the undo function jump to the previous cursor position? That works fine for tidying but if perltidy dumps a lot of errors messages into my file and I undo with [U] I'm left with my cursor at the beginning of the file ...

Answer (score 9):

The command to filter the entire buffer through an external program is:

```
:%!command
```

Put the following in `~/.vimrc` to bind it to Ctrl-F6 in normal mode:

```
:nmap <C-F6> :%!command<CR>
```

For added fun:

```
:au Filetype perl nmap <C-F6> :%!command<CR>
```

This will only map the filter if editing a Perl file.

Comment: Remove the initial : if putting it in .vimrc. It's only needed for starting a command line within the editor.

Answer (score 9):

My tidy command:

```
command -range=% -nargs=* Tidy <line1>,<line2>!
  \perltidy (your default options go here) <args>
```

If you use a visual selection or provide a range then it will tidy the selected range, otherwise it will use the whole file. You can put a set of default options (if you have any) at the point where I wrote `(your default options go here)`, but any arguments that you provide to `:Tidy` will be appended to the `perltidy` commandline, overriding your defaults. (If you use a `.perltidyrc` you might not have default args -- that's fine -- but then again you might want to have a default like `--profile=vim` that sets up defaults only for when you're working in vim. Whatever works.)

Answer (score 4):

Taking hobbs' answer a step further, you can map that command to a shortcut key:

```
command -range=% -nargs=* Tidy <line1>,<line2>!perltidy -q
noremap <C-F6> :Tidy<CR>
```

And another step further: Only map the command when you're in a Perl buffer (since you probably wouldn't want to run perltidy on any other language):

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.pl,*.plx,*.pm command! -range=% -nargs=* Tidy <line1>,<line2>!perltidy -q
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.pl,*.plx,*.pm noremap <C-F6> :Tidy<CR>
```

Now you can press Ctrl-F6 without an active selection to format the whole file, or with an active selection to format just that section.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a new keyboard shortcut, how about replacing the meaning of the `=`  command which is already in people's finger memory for indenting stuff? Yes, perlcritic does more than just indent but when you use perlcritic anyways, then you probably don't want to go back to the inferior "just indent" `=` command. So lets overwrite it!

```
filetype plugin indent on
autocmd FileType perl setlocal equalprg=perltidy
```

And now we can use `=` just like before but with the added functionality of perlcritic that goes beyond just indenting lines:

```
==   run perlcritic on the current line
5==  run perlcritic on five lines
=i{  Re-indent the 'inner block', i.e. the contents of the block
=a{  Re-indent 'a block', i.e. block and containing braces
=2a{ Re-indent '2 blocks', i.e. this block and containing block
gg=G run perlcritic on the entire buffer
```

And the best part is, that you don't have to learn any new shortcuts but can continue using the ones you already used with more power. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to select text using line oriented visual <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then I press <kbd>:</kbd> an I have `!perltidy -pbp -et4` somewhere in history so I hit once or more up arrow <kbd>⇧</kbd>.